# Pywin32, write custom mail at outlook from word

Tags: python, outlook, ms-word, pywin32, win32com

I would like to write custom mail and mail contents are from word.

At last line, I could see different mail format from original message.
I don't understand why .format change format of original message.
I want to keep format of original message.

[I want this format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIBiS.png)

[image]

[customization is good but format is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBNJC.png)

[image]

```
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd

path = r'C:\Data\Test.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name='Sheet1')

word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
doc = word.Documents.Open('c:\Data\Message.docx')

doc.Content.Copy()

doc.Close()

subject = 'email subject'
recipient = 'email@domain.com'

#Create and send emailzxsxnbhg  
olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = subject
newMail.GetInspector.WordEditor.Range(Start=0, End=0).Paste()
newMail.To = recipient
newMail.display()
newMail.Body = newMail.Body.format(Name = df.loc[0,'Name'], Title = df.loc[0,'Title'])
```

Comment: have you tried `.HTMLBody`?

Comment: Yes, I already tried it. Mail format is changed to fully string.